# -python - concatenate text file and store it into variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate two text file without writting the result into a another file, but just store it in a variable? 
What I'm looking for is something like

```
my_fun(cat(file1,file2))
```

where `my_fun` will read the result of the concatenation **cat** and use it as if it was a real text file.

In other word, I'd like to do

```
with open(my_fileOut,'w') as outfile:
   for file in [file_1,file_2]:
      with open(file,'r') as infile:
          for line in infile:
              outfile.write(line)
```

and remplace `my_fileOut` with a variable and therefore not make `outfile.write(line)` but store the result in memory

Thanks a lot in advance for any help or piece of advice,

Regards

PS : Sorry if my english is not very good

Comment: What does *use it as if it was a real text file* mean exactly?

Comment: Just what Jon Clements says... you'll have to specifiy which file operations you're using in `my_fun()`

Comment: Are you trying to store it in a `File` object? Or just the `str` content in a variable?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers wondering if `io.StringIO(''.join(fileinput.input(['filename1', 'filename2']))` will cover it...

Comment: thanks for your answers,
So I'm using a tools found on github which take a file.txt as first argument (`my_fun`) but I'd like to use many of them at once. That why I need to concatenate and then use the result.
So far `my_fun` uses `open(file)` but I'll have to change that too.

what's a File object w.r.t a string?

Comment: With your update, the `StringIO` library is best as @JonClements noted.

Comment: yes, it looks good. Doesn't work so far (for others reasons) but I'm one it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to write a file in the end. So why not?:

```
def cat(f1, f2):
    with open(f1, 'r') as f:
       f1txt = f.read()
    with open(f2, 'r') as f:
       f2txt = f.read()

    return f1txt + f2txt

def my_fun(f3, text):
    with open(f3, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

out = '/path/to/some/file'
file1 = '/path/to/file1'
file2 = '/path/to/file2'

my_fun(cat(file1, file2))
```

This will read all the data inside `file1`, then `file2` and then add all the data from `file2` to the **end** of the `file1` data. If you mean to concatenate another way, please specify.

Comment: I'd like not to create another file because it is part of a bigger project and I might not be able to do so.
I will try what you have explained and let you know.
Thanks

Comment: @Ezor Then you need to update your post. You've included a `with open()` and an `outfile.write()` which will write to file on disk.

Comment: Hi @pstatix
your `cat` function seems to be as simple as it is effective. If I can make my function `my_fun` read string instead of file path, it will be very helpfull.  :)

What I write in my initial post was an example, but you right, it is unclear. I'll change it.

Comment: @Ezor I think the confusion lies with what `my_fun` needs to do. If you run my `cat` function, you get back a `str`. If you store that `str` in a variable, lets say `combined`, if you supply `my_fun(combined)` what is it going to do? What do you do with `combined`?

Comment: So far, my function is working with a file thanks to `open('path/to/file')` that's why I'm working on make it use a string instead of the path. Right now, `my_fun(combined)` throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

def my_fun(f):
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip())

with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    my_fun(chain(file1, file2))
```

This works because file objects are iterable, and `chain()` effectively concatenates one or more iterables.

Comment: I'll try this as let you know if it does the trick. Thanks for your help anyway